# acquia drupal error after installing via web platform on iis 7.5

Tags: drupal, iis-7.5

I just installed Acquia Drupal using the web platform installer. The entire process went smoothly but when i try to browse the website it say "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Detailed Error Information
Module  FastCgiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler PHP_via_FastCGI
Error Code  0x00000000
Requested URL   http://localhost:8088/index.php
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\acquia-drupal\index.php
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous

I'm running IIS 7.5 on windows 7.

Please help i've been stuck on this since 2 days now.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably late but you just have to navigate to:

http://localhost/acquia-drupal/install.php